# How can I blur my background image in css?

Tags: html, css

I blur my background image in body element using `filter: blur(5px);` The problem is instead of the background image, my content inside the div is the one that is affected.

[image]
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZrIb6.png)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
    <style>

    body {
        width: auto;
        margin:0;
        padding:0;
        /*background-color: #2E3137; */
        background-image: url("images/StockSnap_Q6PIRY9O7M.jpg");
        background-position: center center;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-attachment: fixed;
        background-size: cover;
          -webkit-filter: blur(5px);
         -moz-filter: blur(5px);
        -o-filter: blur(5px);
        -ms-filter: blur(5px);
         filter: blur(5px);

    }

    @font-face {
        font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif; /*a name to be used later*/
        src: url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto'); /*URL to font*/
    }

    * {
        border-collapse: collapse;
    }

    h2 {
        text-align: center;
    }

    .container {
        width: 960px;
        height: 500px;
        margin: 50px auto;
        position: relative;


    }

    .row {
        width: 320px;
        position: absolute;
        top: 50%;
        left: 50%;
        transform: translate(-50%, -50%); 
        font-family: arial;
        /*font-size: 13px;*/
        /*color: #e4e4e4; */
        color: white; 
        padding: 10px 55px 40px;        
        /*background: rgba(105,97,82,0.5);*/
        /*background: rgba(20,21,23,0.6); */
        background: rgb(102, 105, 110);
        border: 1px solid white;
        box-shadow: 0 4px 8px #000000;
        border-radius: 5px;
        font-family: 'Roboto';

    }

    input[type=text],[type=password] {
        width: 97%;
        height: 30px;
        padding-left: 5px;
        margin-bottom: 20px;
        margin-top: 8px;
        color: #4f4f4f; 
        font-size: 16px;


    }

    #login {
        width: 100%;
        margin-top: 5px;
        padding: 5px;
        font-weight: bold;
        cursor: pointer;
        /* display: block; use for centering  */
        display: block;
        /*background-color: #DEE9FF;*/
    }

    #signup {
        width: 100%;
        margin-top: 5px;
        padding: 5px;
        font-weight: bold;
        cursor: pointer;
    }

    </style>
</head>
<body>

<?php
include_once("code1.php");
?>

<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <h2> Sign In </h1>
        <form action="p1.php" method="POST">
            <?php echo form_errors($errors); ?>
            Username: <br/>
            <input type="text" name="username" /> <br/> 
            Password:  
            <input type="password" name="password" /> <br/>
            <input type="submit" name="submit" id="login"/>
        </form>

        <form action="register.php" method="POST">
            <input type="submit" name="register" value="Create New Account" id="signup"/>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please, remove php and all such unnecessary things. jsFiddle would be also good.

Comment: You cannot apply `filter` to a background image...only an element or pseudo-element.

Answer (score 3):

```css
body:before {
 content: '';
 position: fixed;
 width: 100vw;
 height: 100vh;
 background-image: url("http://www.planwallpaper.com/static/images/hexagons-3d-desktop-wallpaper-hd_VUiBHpV.jpg");
    background-position: center center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-size: cover;
      -webkit-filter: blur(5px);
     -moz-filter: blur(5px);
    -o-filter: blur(5px);
    -ms-filter: blur(5px);
     filter: blur(5px);
     z-index: -9;
}
```

```html
<body>
<h1 style="margin: 20px auto; width: 80%; color: #393; background: rgba(0,0,0,0.7); text-align: center">Hello from Breakermind</h1>
</body>
```

Comment: why is the background image not covering the entire page?  I want it full size and adaptable to my screen.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <h2> Sign In </h1>
        <form action="p1.php" method="POST">
            <?php echo form_errors($errors); ?>
            Username: <br/>
            <input type="text" name="username" /> <br/> 
            Password:  
            <input type="password" name="password" /> <br/>
            <input type="submit" name="submit" id="login"/>
        </form>

        <form action="register.php" method="POST">
            <input type="submit" name="register" value="Create New Account" id="signup"/>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>

body {
        width: auto;
        margin:0;
        padding:0;
        /*background-color: #2E3137; */


    }

    body:before {
        content: '';
        position: fixed;
        width: 100vw;
        height: 100vh;
        background-image: url("https://wallpaperbrowse.com/media/images/background-pictures-2.jpg");
        background-position: center center;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-attachment: fixed;
        background-size: cover;
          -webkit-filter: blur(5px);
         -moz-filter: blur(5px);
        -o-filter: blur(5px);
        -ms-filter: blur(5px);
         filter: blur(5px);
    }

    @font-face {
        font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif; /*a name to be used later*/
        src: url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto'); /*URL to font*/
    }

    * {
        border-collapse: collapse;
    }

    h2 {
        text-align: center;
    }

    .container {
        width: 960px;
        height: 500px;
        margin: 50px auto;
        position: relative;


    }

    .row {
        width: 320px;
        position: absolute;
        top: 50%;
        left: 50%;
        transform: translate(-50%, -50%); 
        font-family: arial;
        /*font-size: 13px;*/
        /*color: #e4e4e4; */
        color: white; 
        padding: 10px 55px 40px;        
        /*background: rgba(105,97,82,0.5);*/
        /*background: rgba(20,21,23,0.6); */
        background: rgb(102, 105, 110);
        border: 1px solid white;
        box-shadow: 0 4px 8px #000000;
        border-radius: 5px;
        font-family: 'Roboto';

    }

    input[type=text],[type=password] {
        width: 97%;
        height: 30px;
        padding-left: 5px;
        margin-bottom: 20px;
        margin-top: 8px;
        color: #4f4f4f; 
        font-size: 16px;


    }

    #login {
        width: 100%;
        margin-top: 5px;
        padding: 5px;
        font-weight: bold;
        cursor: pointer;
        /* display: block; use for centering  */
        display: block;
        /*background-color: #DEE9FF;*/
    }

    #signup {
        width: 100%;
        margin-top: 5px;
        padding: 5px;
        font-weight: bold;
        cursor: pointer;
    }
```

live demo - https://jsfiddle.net/grinmax_/fmus0fe0/

Comment: How can i set my background image to full size that is adaptable to my screen size? It seems like my (background-size: cover;) is pointless, since there is width and height that's set to     

width: 100vw;
height: 100vh;

Comment: @studentAir01 in my example, the background is stretched (cover), show me what you have in jsfidle

Comment: it's not full size in my case. There's a white color above my background image. I have added the image on my op.

Comment: understand you, don't use margin-top to first element
look now https://jsfiddle.net/grinmax_/fmus0fe0/1/

Comment: Thanks to all! It's working now. I appreciate your help.

Answer (score -1):

Try this one

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
img {
    -webkit-filter: blur(2px); /* Safari 6.0 - 9.0 */
    filter: blur(2px);
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<h1>The filter Property</h1>

<p>Apply a blur effect to the image:</p>

<img src="pineapple.jpg" alt="Pineapple" width="300" height="300">



</body>
</html>
```